# How to merge two select queries with the correct groups?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have users table with `end_date` column that is either `NULL` if the users are active or it has a datetime if the users are not active anymore

I want to group the users from the same country and city and show the information about `active` users, and another column of `non-active` users but the non-active users only from the last 12 months.

I have the 2 separate queries:

1. For the active users:

   ```
   SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN end_date IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS active, country, city
   FROM user_data_table
   GROUP BY country, city
   ```
2. For the non-active users from the past 12 months:

   ```
   SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN end_date IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS not_active, country, city    
   FROM user_data_table
   WHERE end_date BETWEEN ? AND ?
   GROUP BY country, city
   ```

I have tried with Unions but that didn't work, I've tried subqueries but didn't work either

The result should look something like that:

```
  country   |    city   | active(all time) | not active(past year)
------------|-----------|------------------|-----------------------
Sweden      | Stockholm |        25        |           1
Switzerland |   Bern    |        43        |           13
```

Comment: can you not put the two SUM(CASE) in the same SELECT statement? you'd need to put the end_date range within the CASE rather than part of the WHERE clause

Comment: Ok so I have been using Laravel for a long time with their Query Builder, it made my SQL go really bad. It might just work how you say it

Answer (score 0):

There's many way to do this

here's one of many possible ways

Solution 1:

```sql
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN end_date IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS active, SUM(CASE WHEN end_date BETWEEN ? AND ? THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS not_active, country, city    
FROM user_data_table

GROUP BY country, city
```

Because you asked to merge two unrelated request I mad the assumption that the one you provided in the question is a simple version and you really need to merge the two in this case. you have this way of merging the two of them

Solution 2:

```sql
;WITH B As(
    SELECT SUM(1) AS not_active, country, city    
FROM user_data_table
WHERE end_date BETWEEN ? AND ?
GROUP BY country, city

)

Select A.*, B.not_active FROM(
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN end_date IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS active, country, city
FROM user_data_table 
GROUP BY country, city
) A
INNER JOIN B ON A.country = B.country and A.city = B.city
```

Comment: I think you are missing the `IS NULL` part in the second `SUM` of the first solution?

Comment: For the second solution I get error `Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WITH'`

Comment: I just noticed something how can your first query work your exemple is not correct
it's not possible to be 'between' two 'date' if the date 'is null'

I made a false assumption because I didn't notice that they were a mistake in your request in the first place

Comment: correct, it's supposed to be `IS NOT NULL` and swapped value, edited the post

Comment: No need to test if it's not null because you're already testing if it has a beetween value as result the first solution is correct

Comment: @B.DLiroy for the second solution I can't tell why i would not work maybe i made a mistake I encourage you to look forward how to make a SQL Server `WITH` statement

Comment: @B.DLiroy for the second solution I can't tell why i would not work maybe i made a mistake I encourage you to look forward how to make a SQL Server WITH statement
I edited the answer check the second solution 2 check it again